# how to login with email adress using smack,openfire ,android?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

i have a problem using smack api
i'd like to allow the users to login using their email not username how to do it ?i'm using openfire,xmpp,smack API android

Comment: i have a problem with your question its really vague and doesnt look like you have done any research and also you need to learn how to use punctuation in your sentences otherwise its hard to read like this is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register as username@server

Your email will be the username.

So your JID will be abc@gmail.com@mydmain.com

Since you have twice "@" you don't want to make conflict.

Try to replace the "@" with a "!".

For examle:

Your server: mydmain.com
Your email : abc@gmail.com

The JID should be as: abc!gmail.com@mydmain.com

I hope it help you.